# Yes/ No : Is indiscrete space $(X, \tau)$ have the fixed point property?

Tags: general-topology

Given  $X$ be a set with at least two point .
Now  my question is that

Is indiscrete space $(X, \tau)$ have the fixed point property ?

My attempt : I think yes

Consider $X = \{0, 1\}$ with the indiscrete topology i.e. the ***only two*** open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X = \{0, 1\}$ itself.

Now  define $f: (X,\tau) \rightarrow (X, \tau)$ by
$f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $f(X) = X$ are both open and so $f$ is continuous.

Here $f$ satisfy the property $f(x)= x$ , so $f$ have fixed point

that is indiscrete space $(X, \tau)$ have the fixed point property

Comment: You seem to be conflating functions $f\colon X\to X$ with functions $f\colon \mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(X)$. With $X=\{0,1\}$, what about $f(x)=1-x$? It's still continuous yet has no fixed points.

Comment: Im not talking about discrete topology $ P(X)$.....My question is about indiscrete,,,ya $f(x)= 1-x$ will not satisfied @GregMartin

Comment: Forward images are irrelevant, look at inverse images instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any* function  $f:X \to X$ will be continuous when $X$ has the indiscrete topology (because $f^{-1}[X]=X$ and $f^{-1}[\emptyset]=\emptyset$ hold for all such functions, and these are the only open sets of $X$.)

So if $X$ is any space with more than $1$ point, it will have a function $f:X \to X$ that has *no* fixed points, e.g. $X=\{0,1\}$ has $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$.

So a non-trivial indiscrete space $X$ does **not** have the fixed point property (which says that *all* continuous functions $f:X \to X$ have a fixed point, and there is always a counterexample for any $X$ with $|X| > 1$).

Take $X$ with $p \neq q \in X$ then $$f(x)=\begin{cases} p & x \neq p\\ q & x=p\end{cases}$$ is a simple function on $X$ that has no fixed point.